# Finding instances of Alloy predicate executions

Tags: alloy

Is it possible to search for instances of **predicate executions** (sequences of predicate applications) that lead from a given state to another constrained state?

A somewhat related question: is there a way to pass a predicate as argument to another predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, at least to a reader like me who thinks of predicates as things to *evaluate*, not things to *execute*.

> Is it possible to search for instances of **predicate executions** ... ?

It sounds as if here you are looking for the kind of thing discussed in Jackson's *Software Abstractions* in section 2.4 "Execution traces" and elsewhere (see "trace" in the index).  The basic idea is to

- define a predicate describing an initial state (Jackson's example calls it *init*)
- define a set of predicates describing possible transitions from state to state
- impose a total ordering on states
- define a predicate for checking execution traces that takes roughly the form

  ```
  pred traces {
    init [first] /* 'first' is defined by util/ordering[State] */
    all s : State - last 
      | let s' = next[s]
      | Possible_Transition[s, s']
  }
  ```

Many variations are of course possible.

> is there a way to pass a predicate as argument to another predicate?

No and yes.

No because Alloy uses a first-order logic; all arguments to predicates are sets of atoms, defined extensionally.

Yes because one can of course reify predicates by making a signature that maps 1:1 to a set of predicates, and passing atoms of that signature around whenever one wants to pass a predicate.  This is always possible given a finite number of predicates one wants to reify in this way.  (Please excuse me if this point and the explanation below are crashingly obvious to you; I can remember a time when they were not crashingly obvious to me, and I expect Stack Overflow has some readers for whom they are not obvious.)

Suppose we have two predicate `P` and `Q`, each of which takes an atomic argument `a` of type `Atom`.  And we wish to define a meta-predicate `M`, which accepts an atom `x` and a predicate `Y` and returns the value of `Y[x]`.

```
// First some scaffolding 
sig Atom {}
pred P [a : Atom] { ... // whatever you like }
pred Q [a : Atom] { ... // whatever ... }

// Now the heart of the matter
abstract sig reification {}
one sig p, q extends reification {}

pred M [x : Atom, Y : reification] {
  (Y = p) implies P[x]
  else (Y = q) implies Q[x]
  else x != x
}
```

Depending on why you want to pass predicates as arguments, you may plausibly take this as a way to do so, or as a demonstration of why you might not want to do it this way.  If higher-order predicates are a crucial part of what you want to think about, a first-order system like Alloy may not be the best possible match.

But like other first-order systems, Alloy can with some care and effort be used to support higher-order arguments.  When we apply Alloy to show that a given design has a property P, we are in the most common case supporting a claim that all correct implementations of the design will also have property P, a claim that in Alloy might take the form `all i : Implementation | correctly_implements_design[i] implies has_property_P[i]`.  But an implementation is (simplifying slightly) a relation holding between inputs and outputs.  So any statement about implementations is a second-order claim.  So in generalizing about all implementations of a given design, we are making a first-order argument (expressed in an Alloy model) to support a second-order claim.

If you have a serious interest in using Alloy to make arguments about second-order propositions, you will want to consult sections 3.2.3, 5.2.2, and 5.3 in Jackson's book.

Comment: Mr. Sperberg-McQueen, thank you for your answer. I find it very informative and I especially appreciate your polite manner. 

The explanation why it is not possible to directly pass predicates to other predicates and how to circumvent it in Alloy is quite clear to me now. /to be continued due to the limitation on comment length/

Comment: Regarding my first question: it is the ProB Animator and Model Checker I have on my mind, particularly its capability to present sequences of operations which lead to the violation of the specified validity conditions. Execution Traces might be close to it but I've missed to study it thoroughly, partly due to the first impression that the sequence of predicates to be checked must be defined for Alloy instead of the Alloy Analyzer presenting them in its 'magical' way, just like it finds universes answering constraints.